# Malformed JSON in slim framework

Tags: arrays, json, slim

I have this in a **route**:

```
echo '{"result":{"code":"200","status":"success","data":'.$response->withJson($rows,200,0).'}}';
```

that returns this JSON:

```
{"result":{"code":"200","status":"success","data":HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8 [{"id":23,"ragionesociale":"consumatore","indirizzo":"000","comune":"000","provincia":71,"cap":"000","idprovincia_camera":71,"telefono":"000","fax":"000","sitoweb":"0","email":"info@000.it","codice_promo":"xxxxx","password":"xxxxx","data_adesione":"2014-09-26 07:52:23","attivato":1,"costo":0,"tipologia":1,"iva":22,"alias":"prova-it4italy-srl","pagamento":1,"merchantorderid":null,"mybankid":null,"pending":0,"paymentid":null,"logo":"","nome":null,"cognome":null,"sesso":1,"datanascita":null,"eta":null,"nazione":null,"tipologia_utente":1,"fb_token":null,"fb_id":null,"gp_token":null,"gp_id":null,"profile_img":null,"citta":null,"param":null}]}}
```

the problem is that I receive a second response header inside the data, that breaks the JSON.
I would like to have a response of this kind:

```
{"result":{"code":"200","status":"success","data":[{"id":23,"ragionesociale":"consumatore","indirizzo":"000",....
```

Is there a way in slim to do not print the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8` part in the JSON?

Comment: You use withJson method to get help with the headers from slim, if you don't want that, simply use json_encode  function. But I suggest you stick with $response->withJson method and manage your data ($rows and other stuff) before encoding them as json.

Comment: It looks like you are over-complicating it. Normally if you have some data to return as JSON you would simply do `return $response->withJson($data);` This automatically sets a status code of 200 and implies a successful result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `$response->withJson()` the Content-Type of the Response is automatically set to `application/json;charset=utf-8`, along with the default 200 HTTP status code. So you don't have to add that manually.

See [response->withJson()](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html#returning-json)

So just doing the following should be sufficient.

```
$result = new stdClass(); 
$result->result = new stdClass(); 
$result->result->code = "200";
$result->result->status= "success";
$result->result->data = $rows;

echo $response->withJson($result);
```